# Why model.predict() is getting worse accuracy than model.fit() with the same x_train?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, predict

images receives an array of images loaded with cv2

```
images=np.array(images)
labels=np.array(labels)

idLabels=[]
for i in labels:
    idLabels.append(dicTipos[i])
labels=np.array(idLabels)

images = np.array(images, dtype = 'float32')
print("images done")
print("labels", labels)
labels = np.array(labels, dtype = 'int32')


x_train=images
y_train=labels
```

I defined the model and after that I use fit()

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
              metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)
```

The final line of the output is:

```
Epoch 10/10
25/25 [==============================] - 101s 4s/step - loss: 0.0047 - accuracy: 0.9987
```

Immediately I use predict() function and the accurary is really bad:

```
predicted=model.predict(x_train)
rounded_predictions=np.argmax(predicted,axis=1)
temp = sum(y_train == rounded_predictions)
temp=temp/len(y_train)
print("Accuracy:  ", temp)
```

Output:

```
Accuracy:   0.12625
```

I don't know why this (worse accuracy than fit) could happen if I'm setting the same x_train for training and the same x_train for testing

Comment: Please try `model.evaluate(x_train, y_train)`, and update your post with the result (not sure that what you are doing after `predict` is correct).

Comment: I'll try. After `predict()` it receives a prediction of softmax, because my model has this final layer `model.add(layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax'))` , so I'm getting the class indexes of the x_train.

Comment: Again, what is the result of `model.evaluate(x_train, y_train)`?

Comment: `7/7 [==============================] - 4s 589ms/step - loss: 136.1504 - accuracy: 0.1250` That is the output. I use in my model Batch Normalization, I read that could affect, but I don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should directly use the accuracy metrics that you compiled with the model. This will ensure you get accuracy evaluated the same way when training and testing

Try:

```
perf = model.evaluate(x_train, y_train,return_dict = True)
print (perf)
```

Comment: I'm new, where should I set accuracy metrics for evaluate()? I set that in model.compile befor using fit like I showed, but I'm not sure if you mean that. The output of  the two lines is 
`7/7 [==============================] - 5s 627ms/step - loss: 146.0991 - accuracy: 0.1250 {'loss': 146.09913635253906, 'accuracy': 0.125}`